# Connecting Azure to Quickbooks Online with OAuth 2.0

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, quickbooks-online

To start, please keep in mind that I am not very experienced with coding and it would be greatly appreciated if any replies were made with clear instructions or links to resources that were fairly straight forward for a beginner.

With that out of the way, my current situation is that I need to move data automatically from a third party source into Quickbooks Online using Azure and I have very little idea how to set up the OAuth 2.0 connection to receive a valid token. I've done a test connection using Postman, successfully received a valid token, and have been able to send and receive data using the Quickbooks API. However, being able to do the same from inside of Azure (whether using AD or Logic Apps) escapes me. Please note that this needs to be a service-service connection with no user input required (e.g. no logins or prompts). I've tried setting up a GET request in Logic App to start the workflow to first receive the code by using the client_id, client_secret, and scope that is provided in the Quickbooks deverloper app keys section but it always comes back as permanently moved or a bad request. I think this is due to a bad URI but again, I'm not familiar with what URI I should be using in the GET request or even if the GET request is what I should be using in the first place. The next step of course would be to send the code and request the actual token.

My current research has only revealed information on authenticating to an AD app but all of the instructions seem to be mixing information from the old Azure platform making the process unusable. On the Quickbooks side, the information is all about creating Quickbooks apps for publication on their marketplace, which is not the goal here.

If anybody can help with this I'd appreciate it as I've spent the last couple of days trying to figure this out and getting nowhere.

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "method": "GET",
        "uri": "xxxx", //This is what I need to know and where to find it
        "headers": {
            "client_id": "xxxx", //provided by quickbooks dev app
            "client_secret": "xxxx",  //provided by quickbooks dev app
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "scope": "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting"
        }
    },
    "recurrence": {
        "frequency": "Minute",
        "interval": 3
    }
}
```

Error with current URI is "bad request" because it is missing api-version but could also be caused by the # symbol.

Comment: You're telling us a story. Please go straight to the point: put your code, errors, findings and finally what your question is. Cheers

Comment: Sorry about the WOT just trying to make it clear what I was trying to accomplish.